# Android What permissions required to call PowerManager.goToSleep(n) put device in sleep mode?

Tags: android

Already set android.permissions.DEVICE_POWER in manifest of my app. Still complains that  neither user nor process have this permission when I call PowerManager.gotoSleep(n) within activity. What other settings are required for this to work?  Thanks  This is on My Samsung ATT phone

Answer (score 3):

DEVICE_POWER is  a level 2 permission and protected  permission and hence it is not provided to any app  which  request it via manifest, to get this permission  successfully  we need to  have Platform certificate in our make file  and shared user id  set in  manifest as system...

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform (makefile entry)

android.uid.system (shared  user id )
```

There  isnt a  way around  this  i have  looked  around havent  found any ...

Comment: Hi. Do you give me a reference where I can get in details step about this or would you please describe in more details.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on a rooted device?

Comment: @user2103379  check the  solution given by "repat" below . cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In old version, I read that it is a signature-protected permission, i.e. only apps that got
signed as system apps are allowed to.

Comment: What is involved in getting app signed as system app?  what if device is rooted? Thanks

Comment: this can be answered as on separate question here:

Comment: old version means 2.1 or pre 2.1?

Comment: Also are there other ways to put device in sleep mode programatically? Like issuing an intent?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 bin/TestApp-unsigned.apk bin/TestApp.apk
```

I had the exact same problem and this worked for me. Get signapk.jar from https://github.com/appium/sign. the repository also includes the Android test certificate, which works e.g. with a rooted nook.