# How to call the event "screen_off", when running my app?

Tags: android

How to call the event "screen_off", when running my app? for example 5 seconds after the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will turn the screen off for the specified amount of time:

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this requires signature permission DEVICE_POWER, which most applications are unlikely to hold: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710971/android-what-permissions-required-to-call-powermanager-gotosleepn-put-device-i

Answer (score 1):

in displayOffTime=5*1000;//5 seconds

following code will make screen off after 5 seconds

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, displayOffTime);
```

Comment: more detail, please. how to call class Settings (I'm new to android)

Comment: This approach sets the time at which an idle screen turns off. It does not actively turn off the screen.