# Turn off the screen in android

Tags: android, android-widget, screen, system, listener

I google this and there is a lot of examples in handling the even on_screen_of and on_screen_off, but I want to actually turn on and turn off the screen. Every search I made it lead me on handling the screen on and off event.

I want to have a button that when clicked will turn the screen off.

How can I do this, and what permissions do I need ? or I this is talked before please give me some useful link

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);
```

You will probably need this permission too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android)

Comment: it throws Neither user 10079 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.
But in my manifest I provide the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" /> and still throws the exception, any ideas why ?

Comment: The `DEVICE_POWER` permission can't be used by normal apps, they have to be signed as system apps. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710971/android-what-permissions-required-to-call-powermanager-gotosleepn-put-device-i) and the links within the answers.