# How to put a device to sleep mode

Tags: android

I am doing one application for that I need to put a android device to sleep mode. How to put a device to sleep mode and how to wake-up a device when it is in sleep mode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> How to put a device to sleep mode

You don't. You allow the device to fall asleep of its own accord, when the user is done working with it, based upon the user's preferences as set up in Settings.

> how to wake-up a device when it is in sleep mode.

If it is supposed to wake up at a certain time, use `AlarmManager` with a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`. The device will stay awake long enough for your `BroadcastReceiver` to be called with `onReceive()`. Once `onReceive()` returns, the device can fall back asleep. If your work is too long to do in `onReceive()`, you will need to delegate that work to some other component (e.g., an `IntentService`) and use a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake long enough for you to complete the work **and no longer**.

Comment: What about [`PowerManager.goToSleep(long time)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep(long))?

Comment: @Jakar: That's protected by a permission (`DEVICE_POWER`) that normal SDK applications cannot hold. Unfortunately, this requirement is not mentioned in the JavaDocs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710971/android-what-permissions-required-to-call-powermanager-gotosleepn-put-device-i

Comment: I thought that might have been the case. Thanks for clarifying.