# How to put Android to standby programmatically?

Tags: java, android

Is it somehow possible to set Android to standby-mode programmatically ?

Comment: And what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're developing your own ROM or you have a rooted phone (it's need to be checked which user is able to do this) then you should have a look to the PowerManager.goToSleep functionality. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/lDErgJMEK-s) is a discussion about this function in the Google Groups. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710971/android-what-permissions-required-to-call-powermanager-gotosleepn-put-device-i) you can read about this particular permission.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29

This is what i think you are looking for.
Don't forget to include following permission.

```
android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you know that is a Question & Answer based forum? Do you think yours is an answer? You should provide some examples, or at least specify something more than displaying a constant and a link to an API.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been removed since API level 21: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.os.PowerManager.html

Like Yury also mentioned, before you were able to call `powerManager.goToSleep(time)`, but you would have needed a rooted device or app would have needed to be signed as a system app to acquire the relevant rights.