# Attempting to put Android device to sleep, but the PowerManager does not contain a "goToSleep(long) method

Tags: java, android, powermanager, sleep-mode

I am attempting to put a device to sleep and I have found [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734353/hwo-to-set-android-to-standby-programmatically) all over about using the PowerManager class's goToSleep(long) method but I do not see it in the documentation and it does not work when I attempt to using it in my code.

[Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) does not contain a goToSleep method that I could see.

My Code:

```
 private void sleepDevice() {
    try {
        PowerManager powerMgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        long time = 1000;
        powerMgr.goToSleep(time);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        updateStatus("Error attempting to reboot device.");
        updateStatus(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Android Studio does not let the code compile with the message, "Cannot resolve method 'goToSleep(long).

I don't even see this method as deprecated.  Also, I don't need to worry about security permissions, the call is intended to run on rooted devices or fail elegantly on non-rooted devices.

Comment: My question is, is there another method/technique that I can use to put an Android device to sleep?  Is this method is another class?  Where did the goToSleep method go?

Comment: `goToSleep()` was removed from `PowerManager` in API level 21 (Lollipop), why I don't know. https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/preview-21/changes/android.os.PowerManager.html

Comment: [old Android docs (thanks to Web Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140721142329/https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep(long)) also state you would have needed DEVICE_POWER permission which isn't available to 3rd party apps on unrooted devices.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippReichart, that was very confusing.  Seeing references in the message boards but no where in the documentation or API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DeviceAdministrator , but you need the user to grant you those rights.

Comment: The device administration APIs only let you lock the device, AFAIK. Whether that qualifies as "put it to sleep" for the OP's needs or not, I do not know.

Comment: @CommonsWare - yes you are right :D, it all depends on the needs of the  OP

Comment: @DanieIM. Thanks for the help.  I actually just need the screen to power off but I do not want to lock the device.  It was decided that we can ignore this requirement for now.  The closest I got to getting this to work was to set the sleep timer to zero and let the device shut the screen off.  Then, I resent the timer when the user restarts the device.

Answer (score -3):

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager
    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR_OWN_TAG");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

Try this way and give some feedback.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the issue

Comment: This is wrong approach, question is about going to sleep.