# Android going to sleep (standby)

Tags: android, sleep, standby

I want my android device to go to sleep (screen off), has someone an idea how to do it?

- In the past I was using the `PowerManager` function `goToSleep(time)`, but apparently this function does not exist anymore, I don't understand why.
- Other topics talk about those lines:

  ```
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
      wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My wakelook");
      wakeLock.acquire();
  ```

But it only allows the device to enter sleep mode, without telling him to go to sleep mode now.

- I already tried the solution which consists of diminishing the luminosity of the screen, but it is not a real solution since the device doesn't really enter sleep mode. And I don't want to use the following code:

  ```
  android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, timeoutInactivity);
  ```

  because I don't want to touch the screen display settings and it is more a workaround than a solution.

PS : It's for a system app, so I don't have any right/permission limitation.

Comment: There is a goToSleep(time) method in power manager class. Just check that.But for sleep you should disconnect your USB source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm working with API23 and goToSleep(long) has been removed. When i try "pm.goToSleep(10);", android studio tells me "cannot resolve method goToSleep(long)".

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28459287/1276636). I think the comments there will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I didn't find a solution working in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

public void sleep(){
      mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
      mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't make the screen turn off.